# Why we are moving towards Mixed Programming Paradigm

Tags: object-oriented, procedural

`C` had Procedural Paradigm, then `C++` came with `OOPS` and success of `JAVA` make it best suitable Programming Paradigm.

Now, Look at recent trends, `Kotlin`, `Swift` these languages are not like `JAVA` these are providing a flexible way of coding, Neither Procedural nor OOPS, and also these languages are being accepted widely.

Is it going to make programming easier and programmer a little more away from system understanding?

In other word, what is the cost programmer going to pay for this Flexibility?

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure we are, I'd argue that Lisp is a multi-paradigm language and as its the second oldest high-level lengauge we have pretty much always had multi-paradigm languages.

C++ also is arguably not an OO language. Its perfectly possible to write procedural code in C++, C++ Templates form a pure-functional language, and obviously there is support for OO as well (even if Kay doesn't like it)

With no evidence at all I'd say that most languages that we tend to use end up being multi-paradigm (Java was somewhat an exception to this at least until recently). Teaching languages tend to be better as single paradigm. But this could just be my opinion

Comment: +1 good answer. Just curious, what constructs make lisp multi-paradigm?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Lisp_Object_System also you can pretty much write procedural code in any language which allows I/O somehow

Comment: Hmm, never learned about OO lisp in college. I was under the impression lisp was purely functional/list oriented

Comment: @TheCatWhisperer: You never learned about Scheme? It was *explicitly* designed as an object-oriented Lisp. After Smalltalk, the Lisp community was the first to pick up on OO and start experimenting with it. Flavors, New Flavors, LOOPS, CommonLOOPS, Object Lisp, Common Objects, … Almost any OO concept that does *not* come from Smalltalk was invented there. Mixins in the Flavors object system, Multimethods in LOOPS, I believe. For how much Rich Hickey likes to criticize OO, Clojure is an amazing OO language. And of course, there's Dylan.

Comment: And in the other direction, Alan Kay was heavily inspired by Lisp.

Comment: @TheCatWhisperer A lot of lisps are more imperative than functional.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that a language doesn't necessarily force you to program within a certain paradigm. A paradigm is more of a way of thinking and constructing your program, while a language is a tool which either:

- *allows* you to code a program in a certain paradigm;
- *supports* the paradigm of your choise natively, or
- doesn't allow you to do certain things.

C++ *allows* you to program in the object-oriented style as well as in the procedural style, and, if we consider templates, as jk. said, you can get pretty close to the functional style of programming. Kotlin, arguably, not only *allows* you to do such things, but also natively *supports* many features that are required to code in all of the mentioned paradigms. On the other hand, Java doesn't allow you to do pretty much anything except OOP. Maybe some kind of functional-style code is possible if we consider Java 8 streams. It is much easier to do aspect-oriented programming in Java and Kotlin then it is in C++.

Some languages limit you to certain paradigms, the others give you more choices. The price of a choice is obvious: when you have more options, it gets hard to stick to a single paradigm all the time, and your code may quickly start to smell.

Comment: +1 Though it can be argued that Java is not particularly suited to OOP. Sure, it has classes and inheritance, but that's not necessarily OO. It can also be argued that whatever OOP was supposed to be, Java overrode that definition with "OO is whatever Java does". For example, to a Smalltalk dev, arguing that Java supports OOP are fighting words :P

Comment: @AndresF. being created to implement a single paradigm and ending up ruining it completely. What an irony :D